# How do I add HTML to WordPress and then add colours?

Tags: html

I'm trying to add color to one of my headings using wordpress - for now its just background colour. When I add a style section, and ask for the h1 to be a heading (with its corresponding closing tag) I get the image below displayed.

```
  <style>body{color: red;}
 h1{color: #00FF00;}
  p{color: rgb(0,0,255)
  </style>


 <h1>My knowledge of html has grown.... (The captains trumpet blasts!!)

 </h1>
```

Here is the research I have done:

I tried to incorporate the techniques included at the fllwing link.
http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Text-Color-in-HTML

I have asked at Freecode Camp Capetown (on the Facebook page)

I have reviewed my notes from learning HTML based on the developers curriculum from Free Code Camp (approximate time spent on the site: 8 hours).

I have looked at online resources elsewhere - including, but not limited to the developers guide for WordPress:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation

I can review the words but they are going over my head.

How? I'm trying to create my online portfolio.

Comment: You want to change first h1 tag in red, am I right ?

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: <style>
    h1 {.red-text {color: red;} 
    </style>

Comment: note that I did the above and (in the wordpress editor) and it still does not appear. Do you think the wordpress editor may block you from making certain kind of changes to html?

Comment: Are you doing this in the editor? If so, you need to switch from the "visual" tab to the "text" tab to add code, otherwise it will just display as text. Also, your closing tag for the style block needs a slash, otherwise the whole page will break. </style>

Comment: The problem is that the style section keeps disappearing after I add it. The site (wordpress) automatically deletes the style section. Is there a code I need to enter prior to entering all this information? Like I said, I have done extensive research.

Comment: @Jackal21: yep, that's it. Assuming you're interested in the link I mentioned above, [that is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/472495).

Comment: @halfer: is it possible to change downvotes to 0; I'm just curious since I made the changes requested of me by the community.

Comment: @Jackal21: I guess you can always ask for individuals to reverse their downvotes, but the main problem is working out who has downvoted in each case. That information is available only to admins and diamond moderators, and is otherwise private. I didn't DV on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put .red-text {color: red;} inside a style tag

```css
<style>
.red-text {color: red;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked thourgh your code.No need to add class to first heading.Just use pseudo selectors.

**HTML code**

```
<h1>red-text</h1>
<h1> My html knowledge has grown.......</h1>
```

**CSS code**

```
h1:first-child {
color:red;
}
```

If you have multiply the same tags. You can use pseudo classes.Have look to different types of selectors

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp